# Xcode 7 keeps crashing opening a project (xcworkspace)

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I have already deleted the `xcuserdata` and installed the pods, please help

> Process:               Xcode [7657] Path:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:
>   com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               7.2.1 (9548.1)
>
> Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-9548001000000000~2 App Item ID:
>   497799835 App External ID:       816142004 Code Type:
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:
>   Xcode [7657] User ID:               501 Date/Time:
>   2016-03-08 14:31:23.339 -0300 OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.3
>   (15D21) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   8FA68617-F453-C688-3C68-1CE8439AAB53 Sleep/Wake UUID:
>   D4A9457B-2985-4548-B57A-8D9462B68A23 Time Awake Since Boot: 20000
>   seconds Time Since Wake:       4600 seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 7C1002 UNCAUGHT
>   EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): data parameter is nil
>   UserInfo: (null) Hints: None Backtrace: